# Unexpected behavior using SHIFT+arrows and CTRL+arrows on emacs (orgmode) + terminal + mosh + screen

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, terminal-emacs, motion

I am connecting in a machine using a terminal, `mosh` and then `screen`. Then, in my `orgmode` file I can't use the shortcuts like SHIFT+up, SHIFT+left or CTRL+up etc. If I press that, it produces something like 2A instead the expected behavior. It leads onto accidental mistakes inserting undesired chars on a source code, for example.

I tried to insert the following lines into my `.emacs` config file but it did not work.

```
;; Fix SHIFT+arrows and CTRL+arrows on screen                                                                                                             
(define-key input-decode-map "^[2A" [S-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[2B" [S-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[2C" [S-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[2D" [S-left])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[5A" [C-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[5B" [C-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[5C" [C-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "^[5D" [C-left]))
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you hit `C-left` followed by `C-h l` what does Emacs tell you about the last few bytes it received?

Comment: @Stefan https://pastebin.com/raw/yjrpgQK7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[` is definitely wrong. It should be `\e[` or `\eO`. `^[` is sometimes used to designate the escape character, which is also control-open-bracket, but there is no such syntax in an Emacs Lisp string literal. You need to use `\e` (or some more cumbersome syntax). Furthermore `ESC 2 A` is not a plausible escape sequence: most terminals use sequences that begin with either `ESC O` or `ESC [`.

To see what your terminal sends, press `C-q C-left` (which will insert a literal escape character, which you can use in a string literal but not copy-paste into a web browser), or press `C-left f1 l` to see how Emacs saw `C-left` (you can replace `f1` by `C-h`).

For example, if `C-left C-h l` shows `ESC [ 1 ; 5 D C-h l` then you need

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5D" [C-left])
```

And chances are that your terminal uses the following encoding:

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2B" [S-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2C" [S-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2D" [S-left])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5A" [C-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5B" [C-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5C" [C-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5D" [C-left])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6A" [C-S-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6B" [C-S-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6C" [C-S-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6D" [C-S-left])
```

Comment: When I press `C-q C-left` I receive `^[5D`. But `^[` is one char and it is in light blue.

I tried to copy/past the result of `C-q C-left`, I tried `\e[` and `\e0` but both failed. What I could try more?

Comment: @Felipe If you actually get `^[5D` with the `^[` as a single character, you can write `"\e5D"` in a string literal, or copy-paste inside Emacs (don't copy-paste in a terminal emulator, that would copy the displayed representation with `^` and `[` as separate characters). But it would be very surprising for a terminal to send `ESC 5 D`. It would be very common for a terminal to send `ESC [ 5 D`, which would show as `^[[5D` with the `^[` as a single character. This is `"\e[5D"` in a string literal, or `(kbd "ESC [ 5 D")` if you like `kbd`.

Comment: I tried it: https://pastebin.com/raw/8QJNwhrB and it did not work yet! :-(  What should I try more?

Comment: @Felipe Once again: `"\e[5D"`, not `"\e5D"`.

Comment: I tried both https://pastebin.com/raw/HDB3GQSB and it did not wok yet. More ideas?

Comment: With this configuration, if you start Emacs and press Ctrl+Left F1 `l` (lowercase ell), what do you see in the lossage buffer?

Comment: Hi! The F1 key does not work in this terminal. It has no effect at all. Any alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: @Felipe You can use `C-h l` instead of `f1 l`. Or even `M-x view-lossage RET`.

Comment: I get: ESC [ 1 ; 5 D C-h l

Comment: @Felipe See my edited answer